# Is it possible to perform gradient descent on a complex valued cost function?

Tags: complex-analysis, gradient-descent

[This article](https://medium.com/@rrfd/what-is-a-cost-function-gradient-descent-examples-with-python-16273460d634) discuss how to implement gradient descent on a real-valued cost function. But I"m wondering if the same can be done for a complex valued cost function?

My thinking is it is not possible because you cannot take partial derivatives of a complex valued cost function, whereas you can with a real-valued cost function, and the gradient descent algorithm takes partial derivatives in order to determine what the next step is. Is this correct?

Comment: Complex numbers are not an ordered field so there is no direction to descend. Cost functions are real valued for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Costs are normally assumed ordered, and there can be no (consistent) order between complex values. Quick: Which is larger, $2 + 3 i$ or $-3 + 2 i$? You could compare them by comparing absolute values, but $\lvert 2 + 3 i \rvert = \lvert -3 + 2 i \rvert$. And you'd be back to real costs that way.